# Migrate CRA project to existing Nx workspace

Tags: reactjs, git, create-react-app, nrwl-nx, craco

I have the **Nx workspace** with React and Express apps created via [the official React tutorial](https://nx.dev/react-tutorial/01-create-application) from Nx docs. Also, I have an independent **CRA project** that has just one commit after using `npx create-react-app` command. I want to add my **CRA project** to **Nx** workspace preserving git histories. How can I do that?

I had read docs pages about [preserving git histories](https://nx.dev/migration/preserving-git-histories) and [manual migration](https://nx.dev/migration/manual) and then tried to migrate the project this way:

1. Migrated **CRA project** to a new Nx workspace automatically used `npx cra-to-nx` command as the [docs](https://nx.dev/migration/migration-cra) said.
2. Added remote repository with initial **Nx workspace**.
3. Merged the branch that contained the new Nx workspace with the main branch from the initial **Nx workspace**.
4. To solve all the conflicts I accepted incoming changes (didn't change the configs of the initial **Nx workspace**).

The migration was successful but then I tried to *serve* or *build* migrated **CRA app** and got this error:
[image: build error]

Where did I go wrong? Maybe I deleted some important configuration when was solving the conflicts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue isn't really connected with migration from CRA to Nx. The problem was in the BUILD_PATH env that was in the `yarn build` script. I don't know why the BUILD_PATH isn't working this way, but when I write it in the `.local.env` file and not in the script, everything is fine.

The weird symbols rendered instead of the error message was the error message in russian. They are rendered correctly if I launch the `yarn build` script from the CRA project, not from the Nx workspace.

The migration approach that I tried to use should work, but you really don't need it. The approach from the [Doing the migration manually](https://nx.dev/migration/migration-cra#doing-the-migration-manually) section of CRA-to-Nx docs' page is fast and easy.

Comment: I wrote about version `14.x.x` of Nx. There is a new [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75300009/what-is-the-best-way-to-import-cra-project-into-existing-nx-v15-monorepo) about `v15.x.x`