# What is the best way to import CRA project into existing Nx v15 monorepo?

Tags: frontend, create-react-app, monorepo, nrwl-nx

Previously I [asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70985050/migrate-cra-project-to-existing-nx-workspace) about the migration of the Create-React-App project in the case of `Nx v14.x.x`. For that version of Nx, there was an algorithm for manual migration. Now there is only an automated migration in the documentation, but it is suitable for those who want to create a new Nx project from the existing CRA app. Automated migration isn't convenient if you want to import the CRA app into the existing Nx project.

Why the Nx developers removed manual migration from the docs? Is there a better way to import my CRA project into the existing Nx project?